# Do ajax requests works if JavaScript is disabled in the browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am developing a web application and am using jQuery to provide a good user interface for users. Therefore, I am using ajax requests and many jQuery functions.

If I disable JavaScript in the browser most of the function will not work because I am sending asynchronous ajax requests for many functions. But how can I handle this? Do I need to rewrite the code without using jQuery and ajax?

Find a below a sample button click event:

```
  $("#renameCategory").live('click', function (event) {
         if ($.trim($("#CategoryNewName").val()) == "") {
             alert("Please enter a category name");
             return;
         }
         var selectedCategory = $("#SelectedCategoryId").val();
         var newCategoryName = $("#CategoryNewName").val();
         var postData = { categoryId: selectedCategory, name: newCategoryName };
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCategoryName", "Category")',
             data: postData,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 $('#' + selectedCategory).text(newCategoryName);
                 $("#selectedCategoryText").html(newCategoryName);
             },
             error: function () { alert('error') }
         });
     });
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ajax requests and jQuery will not work when the client has JavaScript disabled. The best way to make this work is to use the URL from the `<a>` tag href like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("UpdateCategoryName", "Category")">Click Me!</a>

$("#renameCategory").on('click', function (evt) {
        //To prevent the link from sending the default request
        //call preventDefault() on the jQuery event object
        evt.preventDefault();
        //
        if ($.trim($("#CategoryNewName").val()) == "") {
             alert("Please enter a category name");
             return;
         }
         //GET THE URL FOR THE AJAX REQUEST
         var actionUrl = $(this).attr('href');
         //
         var selectedCategory = $("#SelectedCategoryId").val();
         var newCategoryName = $("#CategoryNewName").val();
         var postData = { categoryId: selectedCategory, name: newCategoryName };
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: actionUrl,
             data: postData,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 $('#' + selectedCategory).text(newCategoryName);
                 $("#selectedCategoryText").html(newCategoryName);
             },
             error: function () { alert('error') }
         });
     });
```

You will also need to check for ajax requests in your Controller like below:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCategoryName() {
    ...

    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        return Json(yourData);
    }

    return View();
}
```

This way, if your user has JavaScript disabled, the link will function like a normal HTTP request. If the user has JavaScript enabled, then they will get the Ajax experience. This is called `graceful degradation`.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax call works when javascript is enabled.

You can handle it by server-side scripting, when javascript is disabled, you must do works by post/get requests, so you have to recode your web application.

Answer (score 3):

If a lot of modification is needed for your website to work without javascript, then just force the users to enable javascript. One way to notify users to enable javascript is to use the noscript tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

View stackoverflow's page source to see how they use noscript

Answer (score 2):

If JavaScript is disabled in the browser, the `<script>` tags won't be interpreted and executed in your document, including all your jQuery and AJAX JS code. The most common way to implement interactive web application other than Javascript is Flash, so you can still have a backup plan. You can also go with the old-school server side only generated dynamic pages.

Today, however it is very rare for someone not to have JavaScript enabled, so it should not be an issue at all.

Anyway you can make use of the `<noscript>` html tag to display a message to these users.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ... Js code ...
</script>
<noscript>You have JavaScript disabled in your browser. Please enable it.</noscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously any functionality depending on script will not work if scripting is disabled, not available or incompatible with the environment it is trying to run in.

It is considered by many to be a good strategy to develop web applications so that they work without script support. You can then add scripting to improve the workflow and efficiency, but you will do so knowing that you have a fall back to a working system available if at any point the script should not run.

The discipline of designing and implementing a good workflow based on just HTML and forms may well lead to an easier interface to script and a more efficient workflow.

All too often developers throw together some minimal HTML and CSS, then try and do everything in script. The extreme is to have a DOCTYPE, title element, one block element and one script element that does everything. Not recommended.